# Thread Pool using pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads

So, my questions is how should I create a thread pool of pthreads? I just need to create an amount of pthreads based on a global variable:

```
#define NUM_PROCESSES 10
```

So, the idea is to create an array that stores pthreads so that I may use them as needed. I have a mutex lock pseudo-code setup for controlling which ones will be running. I'm just having trouble how I actually implement this thread creation based on the #define statement.

So the C / idea is;

```
pthread_t *myPthreadIDs[NUM_PROCESSES];
pthread_attr_t threadAttributes;
pthread_attr_init(&threadAttributes);

for(i = 0; i < NUM_PROCESSES; i++){
   pthread_create(&myPthreadIDs[i], &threadAttributes, thread_run, theTime);
}
```

My question is, can you create pthread pointers this way?

EDIT:

So the answer or fixing my mistake is on this line:

```
pthread_t *myPthreadIDs[NUM_PROCESSES];
```

I needed to change it to:

```
pthread_t myPthreadIDs[NUM_PROCESSES];
```

It's important to note that my confusion was with pthread_t type and declaring it so that I could have a pool. pthread_t is not an address and so I did not need to create an array of type pointers.

Thanks for the help @WhozCraig!

Comment: No problem, I'm just asking if you can create pthreads pointer this way? I can't find any documentation or tutorials about making pthreads this way and I want to know if I'm creating multiple pthreads correctly.

Comment: You want that to be `pthread_t myPthreadIDs[NUM_PROCESSES];`

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh, because pthread_create returns the PID I can just store a bunch of thread IDs and then work with the thread pool later in my program? Instead of trying to store addresses (pointers) ?

Comment: You already *are* using pointers to `pthread_t` objects. Each one is at some address `myPhreadIDs+i`. Its a pointer math thing. They're just a contiguous array. This is commonly done for pthread work pools like yours.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ah, gotcha. So, when I do pthread_create(), do I keep my first parameter as &myPthreadIDs[i]?

Comment: @pmac89 you certainly can, or use `myPThreadIDs+i`. Either will work in C.

Comment: FYI: It allocates memory for the stack of each thread you create: "On Linux/x86-32, the default stack size for a new thread is 2 megabytes", etc.

Comment: Thanks @Jay, I don't think that will be an issue as I'm only making 10 threads or less. All I'm doing is learning how to use mutex locks. Though good to note for the future.